# SwiftData: Accessing collection from computed property forces dependency update ?!? and this compute property and so on... cycle

Tags: swift-data

If I comment `let _ = entries` everything goes well, but if not, accessing(not editing) the collection I don't know why forces the view update (dependency change in `items`) and with the view update the computed property `checkingDate` is triggered firing the view update... and so on. Cycle

Why accessing entries forces view update ? If I change `let _ = entries` for `let _ = name` everything goes well so I conclude that is a problem with collection...

Models:

```swift
@Model
final class Item {
    var name: String
    @Relationship(deleteRule:.cascade) var entries: [Entry]
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        entries = []
    }
}

extension Item {
    @Transient var checkingDate: Date {
        let _ = entries // < -- !!!
        //...
        return Date()
    }
}

@Model final class Entry {
    var value: Int
    var date: Date
    init(value: Int, date: Date) {
        self.value = value
        self.date = date
    }
}
```

View:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Query(sort: \Item.name) private var items: [Item]
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        List{
            ForEach(items){item in
                Text("Name:\(item.name), checking date: \(item.checkingDate, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/quaternionboy/LifeKPIs-SwiftData-Data-Model/tree/Profiling-LifeKPIs-Tests

Comment: Have you tried a) using the computed property without the @Transient macro b) moving from the extension and into the main class declaration c) both :)

Comment: Tried a, b and both. Same issue persists

Comment: I forgot option d) yesterday, create the computed property in the view. Of course only relevant if the properties isn’t going to be used in a lot of places.

Comment: Fixed in XCode beta 7

Answer (score 0):

workaround

```swift
@Model
final class Item {
    var name: String
    var id: UUID
    @Relationship(deleteRule:.cascade, inverse: \Entry.item) var entries: [Entry]
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = UUID()
        entries = []
    }
}

extension Item {
    private var _entries: [Entry]? {
        return try? self.context?.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Entry>(predicate:#Predicate<Entry>{
            $0.item.id == id},sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\Entry.date, order: .forward)]))
    }
}

extension Item {
    func checkingDate()->Date?{
        let _ = _entries
        //...
        return Date()
    }
}
```